# Java, project panama and how to deal with Hunspell 'suggest' result

Tags: java, hunspell, project-panama

I'm experimenting with [Hunspell](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell) and how to interact with it using [Java Project Panama](https://jdk.java.net/panama/) (Build 19-panama+1-13 (2022/1/18)). I was able to get some initial testing done, as in creating a `handle to Hunspell` and subsequently using that to perform a spell check. I'm now trying something more elaborate, letting Hunspell give me `suggestions` for a word not present in the dictionary. This is the code that I have for that now:

```
public class HelloHun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MemoryAddress hunspellHandle = null;
        try (ResourceScope scope = ResourceScope.newConfinedScope()) {
            var allocator = SegmentAllocator.nativeAllocator(scope);

            // Point it to US english dictionary and (so called) affix file
            // Note #1: it is possible to add words to the dictionary if you like
            // Note #2: it is possible to have separate/individual dictionaries and affix files (e.g. per user/doc type)
            var en_US_aff = allocator.allocateUtf8String("/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff");
            var en_US_dic = allocator.allocateUtf8String("/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic");

            // Get a handle to the Hunspell shared library and load up the dictionary and affix
            hunspellHandle = Hunspell_create(en_US_aff, en_US_dic);

            // Feed it a wrong word
            var javaWord = "koing";

            // Do a simple spell check of the word
            var word = allocator.allocateUtf8String(javaWord);
            var spellingResult = Hunspell_spell(hunspellHandle, word);
            System.out.println(String.format("%s is spelled %s", javaWord, (spellingResult == 0 ? "incorrect" : "correct")));

            // Hunspell also supports giving suggestions for a word - which is what we do next
            // Note #3: by testing this `koing` word in isolation - we know that there are 4 alternatives for this word
            // Note #4: I'm still investigating how to access individual suggestions

            var suggestions = allocator.allocate(10);
            var suggestionCount = Hunspell_suggest(hunspellHandle, suggestions, word);

            System.out.println(String.format("There are %d suggestions for %s", suggestionCount, javaWord));

            // `suggestions` - according to the hunspell API - is a `pointer to an array of strings pointer`
            // we know how many `strings` pointer there are, as that is the returned value from `suggest`
            // Question: how to process `suggestions` to get individual suggestions


        } finally {
            if (hunspellHandle != null) {
                Hunspell_destroy(hunspellHandle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm seeing is that a call to `Hunspell_suggest` (created from `jextract`) succeeds and gives me back (4) suggestions (which I verified using Hunspell from the commandline) - so no problem there.

What is more challenging for me now is how do I unpack the `suggestions` element that comes back from this call? I've been looking at various examples, but none of them seem to go into this level of detail (and even if I find examples, they seem to be using outdated panama APIs).

So in essence, here is my question:

How do I unpack a structure that reportedly consists of a *pointer to an array of strings pointer* using panama JDK19 APIs to their respective collection of strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the header here: https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/blob/master/src/hunspell/hunspell.h#L80

```
/* suggest(suggestions, word) - search suggestions
 * input: pointer to an array of strings pointer and the (bad) word
 *   array of strings pointer (here *slst) may not be initialized
 * output: number of suggestions in string array, and suggestions in
 *   a newly allocated array of strings (*slts will be NULL when number
 *   of suggestion equals 0.)
 */
LIBHUNSPELL_DLL_EXPORTED int Hunspell_suggest(Hunhandle* pHunspell,
                                              char*** slst,
                                              const char* word);
```

The `slst` is a classic 'out' parameter. i.e. we pass a pointer to some value (in this case a `char**` i.e. an array of strings), and the function will set this pointer for us, as a way to return multiple results. (the first result being the number of suggestions)

In panama you use 'out' parameters by allocating a segment with the layout of the type the parameter is a pointer of. In this case `char***` is a pointer to `char**`, so the layout is `ADDRESS`. We then pass the created segment to the function, and finally retrieve/use the value from that segment after the function call, which will have filled in the segment contents:

```
// char***
var suggestionsRef = allocator.allocate(ValueLayout.ADDRESS); // allocate space for an address
var suggestionCount = Hunspell_suggest(hunspellHandle, suggestionsRef, word);
// char** (the value set by the function)
MemoryAddress suggestions = suggestionsRef.get(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, 0);
```

After that, you can iterate over the array of strings:

```
for (int i = 0; i < suggestionCount; i++) {
    // char* (an element in the array)
    MemoryAddress suggestion = suggestions.getAtIndex(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, i);
    // read the string
    String javaSuggestion = suggestion.getUtf8String(suggestion, 0);
}
```