# Porting JNA code to Foreign Function & Memory API (FFM), fails for String[] returned from C library

Tags: java, jna, project-panama

Porting JNA code to Foreign Function & Memory API (FFM) (Java 19, JEP 424), fails for String[] returned array from C

C API:

```
    int nc_get_att_string(  
        int          ncid,
        int          varid,
        const char * name,
        char **      value)
```

"Note that unlike most other nc_get_att functions, nc_get_att_string() allocates a chunk of memory which is returned to the calling function. This chunk of memory must be specifically deallocated with nc_free_string() to avoid any memory leaks. Also note that you must still preallocate the memory needed for the array of pointers passed to nc_get_att_string()."

So, one passes an array of char* pointers, and the library returns an array of strings. I have this working in JNA in Java:

```
      String[] valss = new String[len];
      ret = nc4.nc_get_att_string(grpid, varid, attname, valss);
      if (ret != 0)
        throw new IOException(ret + ": " + nc4.nc_strerror(ret));
      return valss;
```

But trying to do the equivilent in the Foreign Function & Memory API in Kotlin fails:

```
        val strings_p : MemorySegment = session.allocateArray(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, nelems)
        checkErr("nc_get_att_string", nc_get_att_string(grpid, varid, attname, strings_p))
        val result = mutableListOf<String>()
        for (i in 0 until nelems) {
            val s2 : MemoryAddress = strings_p.getAtIndex(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, i) 
            val s = s2.getUtf8String(0)  // FAILS here
            result.add(s)
        }
        return result
```

fails with:

```
Symbol is NULL: MemoryAddress{ offset=0x0 }
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Symbol is NULL: MemoryAddress{ offset=0x0 }
    at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.abi.SharedUtils.checkAddressable(SharedUtils.java:344)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.abi.SharedUtils.checkAddress(SharedUtils.java:338)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.MemoryAddressImpl.getUtf8String(MemoryAddressImpl.java:107)
    at sunya.cdm.netcdfClib.NCheader.readAttributeValues(NCheader.kt:365)
```

Anyone see what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Is it failing for all values of `i`?  Seems to be the correct approach referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250218/java-project-panama-and-how-to-deal-with-hunspell-suggest-result)

Comment: Ive only got an example with nelems = 1. Ill look around for a case where nelems > 1.

Comment: I was more curious if it worked for indices 0 thru some number less than nelems.  I'm stumped at this point, though.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me, the element you get from the array is `NULL` though. Is that a possible valid output? You might need to account for that: `val s = if (s2 == MemoryAddress.NULL) null else s2.getUtf8String(0)`

Comment: Also, it seems JNA converts `String[]` into a NULL-terminated array of pointers. I'm not sure what format the function you're calling expects the array in, but adding a NULL element at the end of the array might work (i.e. just allocate `nelems + 1`)

Comment: @JornVernee Looking at [this test case](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c/blob/26dccc25b80f6474982264cef8b18cca1af53132/nc_test4/tst_strings.c#L137-L157) there's no extra null pointer, it's just 16 pointers.

Comment: I can look at the same file with several other tools, and it doesnt appear to be null. Checking for null is a good idea though. Im going to look to see if theres a bug report. Passing an array of pointers that the calling library fills out with malloced strings may not be a common case.

Comment: Heres an interesting bug report that might be relevent: JDK-8235226 : [Panama] jextract support for multi-dimensional arrays of dynamic size https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8235226

Comment: That bug report is for Java 14. Both the API and implementation have changed significantly since that time. The currently open bugs can be found here: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8301239?jql=project%20in%20(JDK)%20AND%20type%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20component%20in%20(core-libs)%20AND%20Subcomponent%20in%20(java.lang.foreign)%20AND%20status%20not%20in%20(Closed%2C%20Resolved)%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC. FWIW, I tested out a similar program here where a native function fills in a string array passed to native code, and this works as expected.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a standalone reproducer to the question as well.

Comment: Ill work on a stand alone case that fails.

Comment: In the case of the Hunspell 'suggest' example, the called library apparently allocates the array of char* and thats the return value. In this case, as evidenced by the working JNA code, the library expects that the caller allocates that array and passes it as an argument, and the library allocates the return strings and places their addresses in the array of char*.

Comment: I reproduced the problem in Java, in case Kotlin was somehow messing it up.

Comment: Suggestion (wild guess here): [create a memory segment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/MemorySegment.html#ofAddress(java.lang.foreign.MemoryAddress,long,java.lang.foreign.MemorySession)) around the `s2` address before calling the `getUtf8String()`.  Since the address is outside of the memory Java thinks it owns, it may be doing ... something.  Likely not null but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the installed C library, and the JNA code sees the same thing. Sorry for the misdirection.